# Comparing two different strings with the same name in c

Tags: c, recursion, reverse, palindrome

I am learning how to code in c right now, as such, the next step in my agenda was learning how to code recursively. For this, I tried to write code that takes a users input, then reverses it recursively and tell you if its a `palindrome` or not.

The current issues number 3, The first is whether or not I have even been writing recursively, the second pertains to which string comparison I have to do in this part of the code to determine if its a `palindrome` or not:

```
int main(){

//char stringran[256];
//char done;
char str1[1024];
int size;

printf("Enter a string to reverse, or done to exit program: ");

scanf("%s", str1);

size = strlen(str1);

printf("The string you enterred is: %s\n", str1);

reverse(str1, 0, size - 1);

printf("The string after reversing is: %s\n", str1);
 //the if-else statement below is the issue, currently i have a  placeholder//
if(str1 == str1){
    printf("The string is a palindrome");
}
else{
    printf("The string is not a palindrome");
}
```

Lastly, if I wish to loop the code so that it keeps asking the initial question after a string is input (Enter a string to reverse, or done to exit program), how would I go about doing it? Would it be a for-loop or a while-loop?.

**Full code with output:**

https://onlinegdb.com/Sk_vTLJp7

Comment: When will `str1 == str1` ever be false? Besides, you can't use `==` to compare strings anyway (any book, tutorial or class, even bad ones, should have told you how to do it).

Comment: `if(str1 == str1)` is always true, and does not check the elements in the string at all.  You want `strncmp`, and you need to compare two different strings.

Comment: Reverse half the string, then compare one half with the other half.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: the worst tutorials are the ones that a programmer failed to read...

Comment: well that's just a  placeholder so the code compiles, I know its true, just how would i go about comparing the string before I reverse it with the string after?

Comment: You will need a copy of your original string to which you can compare the reversed string (with `strcmp` from `<string.h>`). You could also test for palindromicity recursively without modifying the string: Test the outer letters. If they differ, it isn't a palindrome. If not, remove the outer letters from your range and test that. If the range is exhausted, because the begin and end indices overlap, the string is a palindrome.

Comment: If you look at my commented code that's what I was testing for, but then my code becomes longer if I want to display the reversed string @MOehm

Comment: Add your code for `reverse()` here.

Comment: If you want to change a string (reverse it in your case) and then compare the changed string with the original, then you need to keep both strings and refer to them by different names.    Either way, the technique to compare strings in C (where a string is an array with a zero terminator) is to use functions from `<string.h>` (`strcmp()`, etc) and not to use comparison operators (`==`, `!=`, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The current issues number 3"

1. "The first is whether or not I have even been writing recursively."

Yes, your `reverse()` function is recursive.  Any function that calls itself is recursive.  However, it is very easy to write a recursive function that operates incorrectly, does not handle appropriate cases very well, mucks up memory management, or runs on infinitely.  Programming in `C` demands great care; writing recursive functions demands even greater care.

As noted in the comments, detecting a palindrome does **not** require a recursive function.  As an exercise, I suppose it's alright, but (1) if you were faced with this problem for real, you'd be much better off approaching it quite differently, and (2) there are much better problems for learning recursion, because of being both simpler and more suited to a recursive approach.  Google is your friend here.

2. "which string comparison I have to do in this part of the code to determine if its a palindrome or not"

The main thing you need to do is compare two things that might be different.  As the comments point out `str1 == str1` is always `true`.  You point out that this is placeholder code (so that it compiles).  Better placeholder code would be:

```
if (1) {  // placeholder code so that it compiles
```

That would have eliminated quite a bit of confusion.

As for the comparison you need to do, just make a copy of `str1` before modifying it.  Then, compare the pre-modified copy with the modified value.  But be sure you know what you are doing when you make a copy of `str1`.  Since it wasn't already obvious to you that you need to do this, it might not be obvious to you *how* to do this.  It's one of the pitfalls of `C` that it's easy to get this wrong.  Again, Google will help you here.

3. "if I wish to loop the code so that it keeps asking the initial question after a string is input, how would I go about doing it? Would it be a for-loop or a while-loop?"

Either would work, since it's trivial to write a `for` loop that acts like a `while` loop.  The real question is, under what circumstances would you break out of the loop?  The answer to that question will point you to both the best type of loop, and the loop condition to give it.